# Why are TRIM and SUBSTRING not working in this PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote this very simple PL/pgSQL function in order to manage date formats in my database (datetuple is a custom type being a tuple of int's):

```
CREATE FUNCTION date2datetuple (_date text)
RETURNS datetuple AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF _date ~ '[0-9]{4}' THEN
        RETURN (_date::int,
                _date::int);
    ELSIF _date ~ '[0-9]{4}ca' THEN
        RETURN (trim(trailing 'ca' from _date)::int, 
                trim(trailing 'ca' from _date)::int);
    ELSE
        RETURN (substring(_date from '^[0-9]{4}')::int - substring(_date from '[0-9]{2}$')::int,
                substring(_date from '^[0-9]{4}')::int + substring(_date from '[0-9]{2}$')::int);
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function gets defined without any error, but when I input e.g. `'1980ca'` then it throws me this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "1950ca"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function date2datetuple(text) line 4 at RETURN
SQL state: 22P02
```

Upon further investigation it seems that any argument just gets passed on without being modified, which throws an error since `'1950ca'` cannot be cast as `int`. Why are the functions not doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

> Unlike LIKE patterns, a regular expression is allowed to match anywhere within a string, unless the regular expression is explicitly anchored to the beginning or end of the string.

You should anchor the pattern in the first and (probably) second comparison:

```sql
    ...
    IF _date ~ '^[0-9]{4}$' THEN
    ...
    ELSIF _date ~ '^[0-9]{4}ca$' THEN
    ...
```